# How to ignore Parent Layout's backgroud

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to make a layout that can ignore the parent layout's background color.

My scenario is the following

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red"
   >     
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:maxWidth="230dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="15dp"
        >
```

This gives the following results
[image]

Now when I set the last `LinearLayout` transparent, it gets the background color of Parent `LinearLayout` (which is black) and I get the following results
[image]

What I want to achieve is to force `LinearLayout` to ignore its parent `LinearLayout` background color and go past through the parent to see `RelativeLayout` background instead.

The reason I need this is that the `RelativeLayout` could have an image so I want my 2nd `LinearLayout` to see what's on the `RelativeLayout` which keeping `LinearLayout` to color BLACK

How can I achieve this, I have seen facebook doing it with `BackgroundAwareLinearLayout` but is it possible to do it ourselves instead of a library  https://github.com/hieupham1993/background-aware-layout

Basically I want to achieve this without using the library https://blog.usejournal.com/recreating-the-facebook-messenger-gradient-effect-52a1b17c0c3f

I want to CUT A HOLE through the layout 2 and 3 (LinearLayout) to see layout 1 (RelativeLayout).

Comment: `so I want my 2nd LinearLayout to see what's on the RelativeLayout which keeping LinearLayout to color BLACK` , what are u trying to say i dont understand and if u dont want black color so remove the black color , that way u get red color only

Comment: Basically I want to achieve this, without using the library https://blog.usejournal.com/recreating-the-facebook-messenger-gradient-effect-52a1b17c0c3f

Answer (score 0):

You just need something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Message 1"
            ... />
```

then you need to:

1. compute TextView boundaries relative to it's parent
2. get LinearLayout's Background Drawable in Runtime
3. cut that Background Drawable by TextView boundaries (using rounded corners is a more further step I don't take in count)
4. set cutted Background Drawable as LinearLayout Background